# Unable to validate empty json object in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Surprisingly, `validate_json` function is returning false at an empty json object;

```
$empty_json_obj = "{}";
if(validate_json($empty_json_obj)) {
    print_r("VALID");
} 
else {
    print_r("NOT VALID");
}
```

Output `NOT VALID`

validate_json function

```
function validate_json($data) {
    if ( ! $data) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $result = (array) json_decode($data);
    if ( ! is_array($result) || count($result) < 1) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

How to get this right, so that `validate_json` identify correctly empty json passed as `json`

Comment: @Yoshi validate_json function added

Comment: Have you tried to debug your function? It's probably `count($results) < 1` that gives you false on a empty json object...

Comment: @AdityaRewari What would valid json look like? Do you want to know if it's valid json *in general* or according to some *specs of yours*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to test whether the content of a given string is valid JSON or not, it's quite straightforward.

The [manual page for json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) says:

> null is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the nesting limit.

Therefore all you really need to do is test for `null`. Casting to arrays etc is unnecessary (and not every piece of valid JSON is translateable to an array anyway - objects are also very common).

```
function validate_json($data) {
    if ( ! $data) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $result = json_decode($data);
    if ($result === null) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

N.B. If validation fails you can then use [json_last_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and/or [json_last_error_msg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to find out what the problem was.